# How to associate hclust clusters back to the source data frame

Tags: r, text-mining, hierarchical-clustering

I am using `hclust` function to cluster a text based field in a data frame. For this I had to do some text cleaning and thus I extracted the text data to use `tm_map` function for the same. After that I applied a clustering algorithm.

The clustering is working fine but I don't know how to associate the original data frame with the clusters created.

I am new to R and searched for any available solutions online but couldn't find any. Is it possible to do what I am trying?

Comment: `stats::cutree` should make the clusters and then that matches the dtm row for row or the data element for element.

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same question. Here is what I did. Not sure if its correct but seems to work

1) from your hclust object, create a new object with just the ordered column

```
hh1 = hclust(dist(dataMatrix))
DataMatrixOrdered= data.frame(hh1$order)
```

2) Combine Ordered data frame and original data

```
DataMatrixOrderedCbind = cbind(dataMatrix, DataMatrixOrdered[,1])
```